# Batch File || How to freeze command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Not sure if this question has already asked. 
Created a batch file, its working fine. But what I need is, to keep open command prompt when batch is executing. Basically, when we click on batch file, the "command prompt" as soon as batch execution completes. If any error comes I cants see any error. So i want to freeze command prompt. Hope I am clear with my question.

Thank you.
Arfeen.

Answer (score 2):

```
rem Pause if command double clicked
If /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" pause
```

Put above as last two lines. Pauses if double clicked but doesn't pause if typed.

**Run As Administrator**

You need to right click and choose Run As Administrator. Only certain programs show the elevation dialog. Explorer and Task Manager being the two common ones. This script automates right clicking.

```
  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder

    ShVerb <filename> [verb]

  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder

  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator
  of the menu work when used this way

  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running
  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying
  a message box.
```

The script

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo Cmd.doit 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already tried using Pause. But in my case it does not work. Actually, in the batch file i am  doing simple things- 1. go to the exe location 2. Open the desired exe. Pause works well when i m not opening exe. Is there any way to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Post your batch file.

Comment: The executable file itself is a batch file.

Comment: cd c:\myinstaller\
log-viewer.bat

Comment: See the call command. `call /?`. Also see `goto :eof` so type `goto /?`. Just executing a bat file from a bat file transfers control so the first bat stops running. The other command that controls execution is `start`. So type `start /?`.

Comment: Wow!! It worked. Also i tried with Start. You are awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: One more thing, what if i need to run whole thing as admin privilege. I tried google out but the suggested option does not work out. Even it asks for password. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: And also type `exit /?` to be complete.

Comment: +1 `echo %cmdcmdline% | find "cmd.exe /c" >nul  && pause` Is maybe safer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `PAUSE` at the end???

Comment: It works fine. But when i try to execute and exe which is ultimately a batch file, then it does not.

Comment: @Arfeen - how do you execute the batch file.Do you use `CALL` command? Because you need it.....